# Sorting dates in a listbox

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to sort dates, in a listbox that contains three columns, in descending order.

I have two listboxes.  When I click on an item on the first list the dates should appear on the second list in descending order.

The dates are in the second column and are located on a worksheet on a cell(34,i) like this:

```
me.listbox1.list(me.listbox2.listcount -1,1)=ws.Cells(34,i)
```

I tried this code: (Listbox_click)

```vb
Dim y, x As Integer
Dim MyList As Variant

With Me.ListBox_Histo_IT
    For y = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        For x = y To .ListCount - 2
            If .List(x, 1) < .List(y, 1) Then
                For c = 0 To 2
                    MyList = .List(y, c)
                    .List(x, c) = .List(y, c)
                    .List(y, c) = MyList
                Next c
            End If
        Next x

    .List(y, 2) = Format(.List(y, 2), "####.00")
    Next y
End With
```

Comment: The items in a List are not actually dates, they are strings that only look like dates.  You'll need to change your sort algorithm to convert to actual dates, sort, then back to strings.

Comment: I tried to do this ;  If CDate(.List(x, 1)) < CDate(.List(y, 1)) Then, nothing happened.

Comment: MyLIst is storing the wrong item. MyList = .List(y, c) should be MyList = .List(x, c)

Comment: @CDP1802 Well Ive changed it but still not sorting my list in the order I want :/

Comment: Update your post to show the code you have now. You also need the  CDate(.List(x, 1)) < CDate(.List(y, 1)) change. Is it sorting but not in the correct order ?. Give an example of  4 dates that are not sorted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the now code : @CDP1802
It works perfectly 
Thanks to all of you :) 
Dim y, x As Integer
Dim MyList As Variant

```
With Me.ListBox_Histo_IT
    For y = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        For x = y To .ListCount - 2
            If CDate(.List(x, 1)) > CDate(.List(y, 1)) Then
                For c = 0 To 2
                    MyList = .List(x, c)
                    .List(x, c) = .List(y, c)
                    .List(y, c) = MyList
                Next c
            End If
        Next x

    .List(y, 2) = Format(.List(y, 2), "####.00")
    Next y
End With
```